# Using io.Copy with io.TeeReader?

Tags: go

I want to download a file, calculate the hash and be sure that the file is complete.

Previously, I have used `io.Copy` with `http.Get` directly and then, the file would always be complete unless a connection issue occured, `io.Copy` would just keep copying until `Body` was completely empty. Now I have to use `io.TeeReader` also, as shown in this test code:

```
func main() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("https://www.example.com/file.zip")

    f, _ := os.Create("file.zip")

    h := sha256.New()

    body := io.TeeReader(resp.Body, h)
    io.Copy(f, body)

    fmt.Printf("%x\n", h.Sum(nil))

    f.Sync()
    f.Close()
}
```

Error handling is left out for simplicity.

With the above code, can I still be sure that `io.Copy` will always keep copying until `resp.Body` is empty so the file will be complete? or could `io.TeeReader` in some instances, for some reason interfere so the file will be incomplete?

To be clear, I have not see any problems during testing, but I have not much experience with Go, so I want to avoid being bitten by something that could easily be avoided.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find `io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(h, f), resp.Body)` much easier to understand. Conveys the intention much more clearly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

An [io.TeeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) writes to a writer as it reads from a reader. *Any error encountered while writing is reported as a read error.*

In this case the writer is a Hash, and the [hash.Hash](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) interface states that writes *never return an error*.

So using io.Copy() on a TeeReader with a Hash writer is as reliable as reading the Body directly.

(The [implementation of io.TeeReader](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=17021:17062#L518) is surprisingly small.)